# Sorting numbers with typo3 fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid

In my extension, I'm trying to sort a date array in ascending order:

```
<f:for each="{data_eventarray}" as="data_item">
 {data_item.data.eventdate}<br>
</f:if>
```

Output:

```
1645138800
1643756400
1643756400
1645052400
1660341600
1645657200
1646175600
```

Now I want to sort the numbers in ascending order:

```
1643756400
1643756400
1645052400
1645138800
1645657200
1646175600
1660341600
```

I've already tried the following without success:

```
<f:for each="{data_eventarray -> v:iterator.sort(sortBy: '{data.eventdate}' order: 'ASC')}" as="data_item">
{data_item.data.eventdate}<br>
</f:if>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

the `sortBy`paramter of the `v:iterator.sort` VH needs to be an attribute name. You used a (in this context) not defined variable which would result in a string replacement, which is the same for all array items. so no sorting will occur.

try: (Braces removed)

```
<f:for each="{data_eventarray -> v:iterator.sort(sortBy: 'data.eventdate' order: 'ASC')}" as="data_item">
{data_item.data.eventdate}<br>
</f:if>

----
wrong parameter:  

    ... (sortBy:'{data.eventdate}' ...  

correct prameter:  

    ... (sortBy:'data.eventdate' ...
```

Comment: `{data.eventdate}` is the number(date) in `{data_enentarray}`